# Is there a way to capture key events inside a SwiftUI View in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to capture key events inside a view, for example if a user presses the 'Option' key I want to know it happened; something like this:

```
var body : some View {
   VStack { // or any other view
      myView1
      myView2
      ...
   }.onKeyPress { keyeventinfo in
      // invoked only when mouse is inside the frame of the view
      if keyeventinfo.modifier == .OptionKey { ... }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like this approach:

```
.onAppear {
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.keyDown]) { nsevent in
        if nsevent.keyCode == 125 { // arrow down
            //... set for example your local @State var ...
        } else {
            if nsevent.keyCode == 126 { // arrow up
                //... set for example your local @State var ...
            }
        }
        return nsevent
    }
}
```